# Replaces switches and outlets. None of the outlets are working

Tags: walls, receptacle, gfci, circuit

We replaced out our old outlets and switches in our kitchen.  All of the switches work, and none of the outlets will work. The ones we didn’t touch all work!

Comment: so, what's your question?

Comment: Were the old and/or are the new GFCI/receptacles or just plain receptacles? Do you have a non-contact voltage tester and/or multimeter and/or 3-light tester?

Comment: I guess what I’m asking is why would the ones I replaced not work.  The two GFCI receptacles and the two regular ones show no power.  However, the switches next to the receptacle (over the sink light, garbage disposal switches) work.  I will need to buy a voltage tester.

Comment: Perhaps they werent wired correctly.  Please edit the question to provide more information, and pictures of wiring as it was and as it is now.

Comment: You did turn the outlet breaker back on, right?

Answer (score 2):

I just re-read your question, and realized I didn't answer your question. I jumped right into how to fix it. (First post starts with next paragraph.) The reason why the outlets have no power is that the GFCIs are incorrectly wired. They will not reset until properly wired.

99.999% sure issue is with the GFCIs. Most probably have the line and load wires reversed on the GFCI.

Pull them out of the box and look at back.  One set of screws (top or bottom) will be marked LINE, the other LOAD.  I'll assume, for now, that like most people do, you connected the new GFCI exactly as the old one was. Wire on top left out on new top left, bottom left to bottom left, etc.  If so, simply swap the wires vertically, press the reset, and enjoy all those yummy watts at your disposal.

If you just tore the old ones out and randomly reconnected wires to the new one, we have to determine which set of wires is your line and which is your load. If you have anything to detect voltage with (a $10 Non-Contact Voltage Detector works very well for this) find the black wire in the box with 120 VAC.  Once you have black one you need to look into back of box and find the white wire that is in the same cable with the hot black one. This can't be tricky to ensure you have the correct matching wire when there are more than one Romex cables coming into the same hole in The box. If you have a voltage meter you're looking for the black white combination of wires that gives you 120 volts. Those two wires, black and white with 120 volt get connected to the line side of the GFI. Connect the rest of the wires to the load side and you should be good.

If you have no way to determine which wire is hot in that box, just be sure you have the black and white wires paired up with each other and attack one of them to the line side of your outlet. Turn your breaker back on, press the reset button, and if it clicks and latches in and the little light comes on, then you have the line side attached correctly. If it doesn't then remove those wires and attach one of your other sets and repeat until you find the line side.